# Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color in dart

Tags: dart, colors, flutter-layout, uicolor, color-scheme

I am trying to convert this hash color code #159424  **(GREEN-COLOR)** to more darken and lighten programmatically. How to do this please help?

**make green color darker**

```
toDarkColor(String hashColor){
  // how to convert that hash string to make green color darker?
}
```

**make green color lighter**

```
toLightColor(String hashColor){
  // how to convert that hash string to make green color lighter? 
}
```

Comment: Maybe [HSLColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/HSLColor-class.html) class can help.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For people who want to darken or lighten `Color` instead of hex string

```dart
// ranges from 0.0 to 1.0

Color darken(Color color, [double amount = .1]) {
  assert(amount >= 0 && amount <= 1);

  final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  final hslDark = hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness - amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

  return hslDark.toColor();
}

Color lighten(Color color, [double amount = .1]) {
  assert(amount >= 0 && amount <= 1);

  final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  final hslLight = hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness + amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

  return hslLight.toColor();
}

// usage
final lightRed = lighten(Colors.red);
final darkBlue = darken(Colors.blue, .3);
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/29c5577b94571d00926723c85a370e43?null_safety=true)

Comment: When using Zeplin, this post didn't give the correct color. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60191441/1596051 did however

Comment: solution provided by @mr_mmmmore works much better

Answer (score 58):

##### Color accurate solution with no plugin

**The accepted answer changes the tint of colors when darkening** (the tint is more saturated). Also its lightening function produces pure white with an amount of 0.3 for some colors although white should only be reached with an amount of 1.

The two following methods produce **shades of the base color** that seem 'darker' or 'lighter' **without changing the tint**.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Darken a color by [percent] amount (100 = black)
// ........................................................
Color darken(Color c, [int percent = 10]) {
    assert(1 <= percent && percent <= 100);
    var f = 1 - percent / 100;
    return Color.fromARGB(
        c.alpha,
        (c.red * f).round(),
        (c.green  * f).round(),
        (c.blue * f).round()
    );
}

/// Lighten a color by [percent] amount (100 = white)
// ........................................................
Color lighten(Color c, [int percent = 10]) {
    assert(1 <= percent && percent <= 100);
    var p = percent / 100;
    return Color.fromARGB(
        c.alpha,
        c.red + ((255 - c.red) * p).round(),
        c.green + ((255 - c.green) * p).round(),
        c.blue + ((255 - c.blue) * p).round()
    );
}
```

Example: darken a color by 15%.

```dart
final Color darkerGreen = darken(Color(0xFF159424), 15);
```

If starting from a Hex String value as OP asked, use J.M. Taylor' solution:

```dart
Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return Color(int.parse(code.substring(0, 6), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}

final Color darkerGreen = darken(hexToColor('#159424'));
```

**Note**: it's for Flutter projects as it uses the material's `Color` class.

Comment: This does indeed provide better output colors than the accepted answer. +1

Comment: this solution is much better!

Comment: Best answer, Good job

Comment: best solution, making it an extension on Color works like a charm

Answer (score 15):

My solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604669/7479173

```dart
extension ColorBrightness on Color {
  Color darken([double amount = .1]) {
    assert(amount >= 0 && amount <= 1);

    final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(this);
    final hslDark = hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness - amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

    return hslDark.toColor();
  }

  Color lighten([double amount = .1]) {
    assert(amount >= 0 && amount <= 1);

    final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(this);
    final hslLight =
        hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness + amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

    return hslLight.toColor();
  }
}
```

with this one can simply:

```
Colors.red.darken()
Colors.red.lighten()
Colors.red.lighten(0.1)
```

this works on any colors as long as you import the extension.

Answer (score 13):

One liner with built-in method:

```dart
Color.lerp(myColor, Colors.white, 0.4) // 0 = keep as is, 1 = white
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it produces exactly the sames shades as my answer "Color accurate plugin with no plugin" but without the need of custom functions.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [tinycolor](https://pub.dev/packages/tinycolor) package:

```
TinyColor.fromString("#159424").darken(10).color
```

Edit:

You can convert `Color` back to hex string like this:

```
String toHex(Color color) {
  return "#${color.red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}"
      "${color.green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}"
      "${color.blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}";
}
```

or if you want opacity/alpha:

```
String toHex(Color color) {
  return "#${color.alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}"
      "${color.red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}"
      "${color.green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}"
      "${color.blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")}";
}
```

Comment: It will give color. So how to convert color to String hex like #159424 ?

Comment: **Darken gives wrong value** String check = toHex(TinyColor.fromString("#159424").darken(10).color);
    String check1 = toHex(TinyColor.fromString("#159424").lighten(10).color);
    print('#159424----->' + check + '---' + check1);

Dark: give wrong value like "#f6719"

Comment: No, `toHex` returns wrong value (#f6719 should be #0f6719). `padLeft(2, "0")` should fix this - see updated answer.

Comment: Methods like setAlpha(int value) and setOpacity(double value) from **TinyColor plugin is not working**

Comment: Please bear in mind that TinyColor is unmaintained and does not work at all in Flutter >= 2.0.

Comment: Incompatible with dart 3

Answer (score 5):

I used `withLightness` method of `HSLColor` to lighten the color.

```
HSLColor.fromColor(Colors.red).withLightness(0.95).toColor()
```

Comment: And if you want to make the color darker you can use this HSLColor.fromColor(color).withSaturation(0.1).toColor()

Comment: This is way quicker and leaner than other solutions proposed up there, and it comes without requiring external packages.

Answer (score 2):

Since some parts of [TinyColor](https://github.com/FooStudio/tinycolor) seem broken, and I only really needed lighten and darken, NearHuscarl's answer was perfect for me.

However, it was missing one part that was necessary to completely answer the original question, which was converting hash color code (declared as a `String`) to `Color`.

To do that, you can use this:

```
Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return Color(int.parse(code.substring(0, 6), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}
```

The above is not my code, but something I learned from [a tutorial here](https://github.com/seenickcode/fluttercrashcourse-lessons/blob/master/module01-thebasics/lesson06/lib/styles.dart).

Then just combine that with NearHuscarl's code to get the desired effect:

```
final Color darkerGreen = darken(hexToColor('#159424'));
```