# How to specify the contrast between background color and text color when darkmode is present

Tags: flutter

It is a case where there is Text in Container in Flutter.

```
Container(
    child:Text('test'),
)
```

Specify the background color of Container here.

```
Container(
    color:Colors.blue[100],
    child:Text('test'),
)
```

The default text color in light mode is black,
The background color of Container is Colors.blue [100]
So, I will say that this is a design that does not have any problem at the time of light theme.

However, when I switch to dark mode, the text color turns white.
Since the specified background color is still Colors.blue [100], the contrast between the background color and the text color is unclear, and the text becomes very difficult to read.

The first thing that came to my mind as a workaround for this was

```
Container(
    color:Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.blue,
    child:Text('test'),
)
```

If you do the above, the background color will be Colors.blue in dark mode, so it will not be difficult to read.

So this is the solution, but in such cases it feels redundant to manually specify the background color in dark mode each time as described above.

I wonder if there is a smarter way to do it as a framework, but is there anything?
What comes to my mind is whether there is a (smarter) way to solve these problems in a unified way throughout the app using Theme and ThemeData.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432285/how-to-change-text-color-depending-on-background-so-that-there-is-good-contrast

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes,I think it's pretty close to what I'm looking for. I'll try reading it.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign it directly to your theme data this way, and then it will be constant throughout.

```
ThemeData _buildDarkTheme() {
final base = ThemeData.dark();
return base.copywith(
---other theme stuff---
 textTheme: base.textTheme.apply(
          fontFamily: 'Assistant',
          displayColor: ColorThemes.dark.primaryFont),
}
```