# How to increase the brightness of a color?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  var blue = Colors.blue; 
  var fadedBlue = blue.withOpacity(0.5); // Works
  var shiningBlue = blue.withOpacity(1.5); // Error
}
```

Is there any way I can make the blue color a bit brighten say by 1.5x without using any 3rd party package?

Comment: check `HSVColor` class official docs

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360989/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-in-dart

Comment: This can't work. If the brightness of the color is 100%, how could you brighten it by 1.5x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/HSLColor-class.html

```
final originalColor = HSLColor.fromColor(Colors.blue);
final newLightness = originalColor.lightness * 1.5;
final newColor = originalColor.withLightness(newLightness.clamp(0.0, 1.0));
```